# Method org.postgresql.jdbc3.Jdbc3PreparedStatement.setQueryTimeout(int) is not yet implemented.;

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Am New to spring batch. with spring batch job i am inserting data in postgres db then i am getting this error . how to fix this?

Method org.postgresql.jdbc3.Jdbc3PreparedStatement.setQueryTimeout(int) is not yet implemented.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Method org.postgresql.jdbc3.Jdbc3PreparedStatement.setQueryTimeout(int) is not yet implemented.'

This is my datasource code.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <!-- DB connection properties -->
    <property name="driverClass" value="${db.driver:oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${db.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${db.user:}" />
    <property name="password" value="${db.password:}" />

    <!-- Pool sizing properties -->
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="${db.pool.initialSize:5}" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${db.pool.maxSize:25}" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="${db.pool.minSize:0}" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value="${db.pool.maxStatements:10}" />

    <!-- Connection testing and acquisition properties -->
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="${db.con.maxIdleTime:300}" />
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="${db.con.testPeriod:30}" />
    <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="${db.con.testQuery:select 1 from dual}" />
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="${db.con.acquireIncrement:5}" />
    <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="${db.con.retryAttempts:0}" />
    <property name="acquireRetryDelay" value="${db.con.retryDelay:3000}" />

    <!-- JMX name -->
    <property name="dataSourceName" value="Datasource" />

    <!-- Debugging options -->
    <property name="unreturnedConnectionTimeout" value="${db.con.unreturnedTimeout:0}" />
    <property name="debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces" value="${db.con.debugUnreturned:false}" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I'm confused - why does the error say a PostgreSQL method is missing when you have an Oracle JDBC driver class in your pool?

Comment: the driver value is org.postgresql.Driver  I am using postgres sql

Answer (score 1):

The data source looks OK.... @duffymo, the Oracle driver is the default, but would be overridden by the value of 'db.driver' property if 'db.driver' is specified.

The setTimeout error is thrown by some versions of the PostgreSQL driver because they have not, in fact, implemented setTimeout, so they don't want users thinking the setTimeout actually has any effect.

What version of the PostreSQL driver are you using?  Can you share some details of the Spring Batch job?  I'm not sure how to prevent Spring from setting the timeout on a PreparedStatement.  At a guess, you could set db.con.unreturnedTimeout to 0; I'm thinking that value may be passed to setTimeout; but I'm not sure.

Comment: I tried with different version which includes latest one  9.4-1200-jdbc41. But am getting same error. spring batch version   3.0.4.RELEASE. 
I tried with adding the code   ps.setQueryTimeout(0); But error is same

Comment: Can you share more details of your Spring Batch config, and the batch job? Spring Batch's database reader seems to set queryTimeout to -1 by default, and this value of -1 makes it not call queryTimeout at all in the preparedStatements.  Are there any instances of 'queryTimeout' or 'query-timeout' anywhere in your configuration or source code?

Comment: Able to resolve the error the problem is in the parent i am using a different version of driver. Thanks for ur suggitions